# error parsing `Gemfile` expecting keyword_end. Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ROR.  I've searched and searched but can't find this answer.  I think it has to do with not having an 'end' somewhere, but it looks to me like there are the right number of openings and closings. I need another pair of eyes please.
I'm trying to run bundle install with this flag..

```
$ bundle install --without production.
```

The error I get is this:

> There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end. Bundler cannot continue.
>
> ```
> #  from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/Gemfile:22
> #  -------------------------------------------
> #    gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
> ```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.16'
 
group :development do 

  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'

end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do

  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'

  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'

end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2 

group :production do

  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'

end
```

Comment: Please use markup or editor buttons. To mark code sample select it and press `{}` button on editor bar. Do not forget to select answer by press button and vote satisfied answers.

Comment: Just a word of advice while you're early in your Rails (and I suspect, programming) career: when you get stuck, take the time to check the "stupid" things first, like matching parens, quotes, etc. A good text editor can help you by highlighting matching delimiters. The more effort you make before you ask for help, the better you will learn your tools.

Comment: Hey everyone I wanted to thank you for your help.  My BLOC mentor figured out it was just a wierd glitch.  Once I deleted everything and re entered it it worked fine.  I would of never thought to try that lol

Answer (score 3):

Your gem file have typo

replace:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2
```

with:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
```

Comment: while this was an error in my code, after I added the ' I still receive the same error.  This does not solve the error.

Comment: Be carefully, check file, and path, and is it have saved? Or any new typo like this appear at new place. Or so on... The error that you show is consequent of typo that was poineted to fix.